# Why does RDP Licensing, license the same device multiple times?

Tags: remote-desktop-services, licensing, xenapp

I've got a Citrix XenApp 6.5 Farm running on Win 2008 R2 Servers. I purchased 200 Device RDP/Remote App Licenses for ~200 users. We went with Device licenses, because most of the end users use the same machines.

After 1 month of operating, we started to run out of licenses. It turns out the licensing service is consuming multiple licenses for the same machine.

I can revoke licenses, but there is a limit to how many I can do. Is this operating correctly? 
The only explanation I can come up with is that the Licensing service is giving a license to a device for every server it connects to in our Citrix farm.

Comment: @johngardeniers this is not a duplicate because this isn't a question about "is my use case compliant" but a technical question as to why remote desktop is mis counting clients.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers this really isn't about licensing in the sense that's off-topic. It's about the function of the RDS license management role, which is very on-topic, in my opinion.

Comment: @neerpatel can you post something that shows the licenses being mis counted?

Comment: This question is about understanding how the licensing works, which should be addressed to the vendor.

Comment: @John sorry, but I'm really going to have to disagree with you there. It's about how the terminal services license management function operates and it's a technical question about license revocation. This is totally on topic.

Comment: I can see this as on-topic as long as the answers stay along the lines of the technical issue (when licenses get released back to the pool) - I do agree with @JohnGardeniers though: This is probably a better question for the vendor (if for no other reasom then their lousy software is consuming more licenses than it logically should: If nobody complains they just collect the cash for "extra" licenses people are buying to make it work)

Comment: Here is a screen shot of the RD Licensing Manager : http://screencast.com/t/xDSXMxMU
When I select a Installed License key, it lists the computers assigned to each license. As you can see, 1 computer has consumed 5 liceses. 
http://screencast.com/t/d6J6xGk3K

Comment: BTW, thanks for keeping this question open. I searched for my answer on the web and this site, before I made this post. If the question gets answered, it would be a great contribution to this site and the web.. since I couldn't find information on this elsewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug with the licensing service.

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX130004 :

> Microsoft is currently investigating this issue and advised that Per
>   User CALS should be used instead of Per Device RDS CALS.

Also listed on their site :

> **WorkAround**
>
> Microsoft RDS CALS can be revoked manually from the RDS Licensing
>   Manager (20 percent at a time). More Information
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732416.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I `borrowed` this answer but this is basically the same behavior I have seen before.  The one thing most people forget is that TS/RD licenses do not get released back to the pool when the user disconnects, instead they are assigned for a period of time and eventually released back to the pool at which point the client either gets a new license or gets a temporary license for 90 days.

> **Releasing Licenses:**
>
> You can't really do this, and it shouldn't be necessary either.
>
> TS CALs have an expiration date of 52-89 days after issueing. Licenses
>   that are not used (because the client does not connect to the TS
>   anymore) will automatically be returned to the LS after the expiration
>   date. In the meantime, your new clients will get a temporary TS CAL,
>   which is valid for 90 days.
>
> Note that these time periods are choosen to make sure that your
>   temporary license lasts long enough for the old license to become
>   available again. So replacing one client with another can never cause
>   you to run out of TS CALs. If you are reaching the end of the 90 day
>   temporary license period without having TS CALs available, it means
>   that you have been connecting with more clients than you have licenses
>   and you have to buy extra TS CALs.
>
> [Revoking Licenses](http://ts.veranoest.net/ts_faq_licensing.htm#revoke_Device_licenses)

**Trouble Shooting:**

I would first make sure that your Citrix farm is properly using the same license server, or that your license servers are set up in a pool. If they aren't, you will get this round-robin type crap.  The problem you list here sounds like your TS endpoints (Citrix) are not properly assigning a single license.  Either way, you may end up having to call up Microsoft and possibly Citrix to understand what the issue is here.